# Nested IF statements in Excel [Over the 7 allowed limit]

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, nested, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a spreadsheet which automagically gives a grade to a student based on their marks they got.

I've apparently hit Excel's nested IF statement limit which is 7.

Here's my if statement:

```
=IF(O5>0.895,"A+",IF(O5>0.845,"A",IF(O5>0.795,"A-",IF(O5>0.745,"B+",IF(O5>0.695,"B",IF(O5>0.645,"B-",IF(O5>0.595,"C+",IF(O5>0.545,"C","D"))))))))
```

I was reading online that I could create a VBA script and assign it that, but I dont know anything about VBA....so if someone could help me write a VBA for this, would be awesome.

Its still missing the C- grade and anything lower should be awarded a D mark.

This is the grading scheme I am trying to create...:

> A+   89.500 - 100.000   Pass with Distinction
>
> A  84.500 - 89.490  Pass with Distinction
>
> A-  79.500 - 84.490  Pass with Distinction
>
> B+  74.500 - 79.490  Pass with Merit
>
> B  69.500 - 74.490  Pass with Merit
>
> B-  64.500 - 69.490  Pass with Merit
>
> C+  59.500 - 64.490  Pass
>
> C  54.500 - 59.490  Pass
>
> C-  49.500 - 54.490  Pass
>
> D  0.000 - 49.490  Specified Fail

I wouldn't mind going down the VBA route, however my understanding of VB language is absolutely minimal (don't like it)...if this gets too tedious, I was thinking to create a small php/mysql application instead.

Comment: What grade does someone who got an 89.495 get? It's better to just specify lower bounds than ranges in this case.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this much more elegantly with the `VLOOKUP` formula by making separate table mapping lower bounds to letters.  The mapping table must be sorted by grade number ascending.

For example:

### Table

```
A     B
0     D
49.5  C-
54    C
59.5  C+
...   ...
```

### Formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(SomeCell, $A$1:$B$9, 2, TRUE)
```

Where `$A$1:$B$9` is the range with the grade table.  (The `$` signs tell Excel not to move the reference if you copy the formula).
Passing `TRUE` as the last argument will cause Excel to do a binary search to find the value, which (as long as the data is sorted) is exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: I tested this too... works really well :) thanks for that. I was thinking about the vlookup however it freaked me out so didn't bother :P. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Comment: @Alks: this is the right answer - you should click the checkmark to indicate that you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Visual Basic Editor, and insert this code. I don't know what version of Excel you're using, but for versions before 2007, go to tools, Macros, Visual Basic Editor.  For Version 2007 and newer , it is on the Development Tab which is not enabled by default.

Depending on how you want to link it, you could add a button to the page, or call it from the Worksheet_Calculate event.

This assumes that you have the student's total grade  in cell A2, and will put the results in  A2 and B2.

```
Sub Calculate
    dim LetterGrade as string
    dim Superlative as string
    Select Case Cells(1,2)
        Case  >= 89.500
            LetterGrade="A+"
            Superlative ="Pass with Distinction"

        Case  84.500 to 89.490 
            LetterGrade="A"
            Superlative ="Pass with Distinction"

        Case 79.500 to 84.490 
            LetterGrade="A-"
            Superlative ="Pass with Distinction"

        Case  74.500 to 79.490 
            LetterGrade="B+"
            Superlative ="Pass with Merit"

        Case 69.500 to 74.490
            LetterGrade="B"
            Superlative ="Pass with Merit"

        Case 64.500 to 69.490 
            LetterGrade="B-"
            Superlative ="Pass with Merit"

       case 59.500 to 64.490 
            LetterGrade="C+"
            Superlative ="Pass"

        Case 54.500 to 59.490
            LetterGrade="C"
            Superlative ="Pass"

        Case 49.500 to 54.490
            LetterGrade="C-"
            Superlative ="Pass"
        Case <=  49.490 
            LetterGrade="F"
            Superlative ="Specified Fail"

 End Select
        Cells(2, 1) = LetterGrade
        Cells(2, 2) = Superlative


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to simply split the formula into two cells

```
=IF(O5>0.895,"A+",IF(O5>0.845,"A",IF(O5>0.795,"A-",<Other cell ref here>)))
```

Other cell:

```
=IF(O5>0.745,"B+",IF(O5>0.695,"B",IF(O5>0.645,"B-",IF(O5>0.595,"C+",IF(O5>0.545,"C","D")))))
```

Comment: hmmm that would be nice...but I'd like it all in one cell...but i must say, i didn't think about it like that :).

Comment: Smart idea, but will require hiding cells and remembering why they're hidden, and not being able to copy paste easily...

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer the Vlookup method (Slaks solution) for numeric parameters for the simplicity and elegance, an alternative which becomes valuable in case of non-numeric parameters is concatenated IFs.

```
=IF( Case1 , "Label 1", "" ) & 
 IF( Case2 , "Label 2", "" ) & 
 IF( Case3 , "Label 3", "" ) &
```

..... and so on

For example, in this case:

```
= IF( O5 >= 89.5 , "A+" , "" ) & 
  If( AND ( O5 < 89.5 , O5 >= 84.5 ) , "A" , "" ) & 
  If( AND ( O5 < 84.5 , O5 >= 79.5 ) , "B+" , "" ) &
```

..... and so on for other levels.

Answer (score -1):

The VLOOKUP solution seems the best. To add a VBA script, you could bring up the Visual Basic Toolbar, add a control like a Button and then double-click it. The code for that event opens in the Excel VBA environment. There you could add the code in VB, perhaps something like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Cells(1, 2) = getValue(Cells(1, 1))
End Sub


Private Function getValue(ByVal argMarks As Double)
  If argMarks > 89.5 And argMarks <= 100 Then
    getValue = "A+"
  If argMarks > 84.5 And argMarks <= 89.49 Then
    getValue = "A"

  .
  .
  and so on...

End Function
```